# Delete button error

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have been having this issue when I press my delete button I get this error "Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows.", I am using visual basics 2008 and microsoft access for my program.

```
Dim CurrentRowNo As Integer = 0
Dim objDataSet As New DataSet
Dim objDataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Stock", cn)

    If objDataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        objDataTable.Rows(CurrentRowNo).Delete()
        objDataAdapter.Update(objDataTable)
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a DeleteCommand object for this data adapter. You can either manually create the DeleteCommand or use a CommandBuilder to generate them for you.

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf579hcz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information on CommandBuilder objects.

Something along the lines of (untested air code):

```
Dim CurrentRowNo As Integer = 0
Dim objDataSet As New DataSet
Dim objDataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Stock", cn)

Dim builder as SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(objDataAdapter)
builder.QuotePrefix = "["
builder.QuoteSuffix = "]"

If objDataTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    objDataTable.Rows(CurrentRowNo).Delete()
    objDataAdapter.Update(objDataTable)
End If
```

Comment: I found that website quite confusing could show me an example please.

Comment: i have done that however now this error appears "The record cannot be deleted or changed because table 'Order line' includes related records."

Comment: That is because your Stock table has related records in the Order Line table. You're going to have to rethink the design on this one. It's not going to be a simple update the table based on the DataTable. If you are deleting a Stock item, your order item table no longer references a valid Stock item.

Comment: Do you have any suggesstions

Comment: I don't know enough about your situation to give any real guidance. You'll need to think about things like: If I delete a Stock item, what should happen in my OrderItems table where someone ordered that item? Should it delete the order item, should it update the record at all? Should you really be able to delete a stock item or should it just no longer be sellable? There's a million possibilities that are going to change depending on your business rules.